# Safe to delete /System/Library/Caches/com.apple.kext.caches?

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, kernel

On a Snow Leopard machine, is it safe to delete the contents of the `/System/Library/Caches/com.apple.kext.caches/` directory? In install logs, it is seemingly the cause of a failed install of a kernel extension.

Comment: Try `sudo kextcache -e` in Terminal first. This rebuilds the kext caches.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, deleting the caches just means they'll have to be rebuilt on the next boot, so the next boot will take a few extra seconds.